# Find missing character(s) from a string

Tags: javascript, string

My goal is to find which characters are missing from a specific string.
For example, find a missing number: If my string is supposed to have numbers 0-9, but the number `5` is missing, I will get it back.
Thanks for helping!

**Note:** Unfortunately, I don't have any code to share, because I couldn't think of any way to accomplish this.

**EDIT:** This system should apply for all kinds of characters, not only for numbers.

Comment: What isn't working with your solution? Share your efforts!

Comment: I couldn't manage to think of any way to accomplish this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?  Make an array of your character set, loop though it and trigger an alert (or do something) if there is no match:

```js
str = '123467890';
test = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'];
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  match = str.match(test[i]);
  if (!match) {
    alert(test[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: To extend this to characters, just extend the `test` array.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solution is just what I needed - find the missing character from an array!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `indexOf` function for each of the elements that should be contained in the string.

In case of the Numbers 0-9:

```
var str = "012346789";
var i;
var missing = [];
for(i=0; i<=9; i++) {
  if(str.indexOf(i) == -1) missing.add(i);
}
// 'missing' now contains the missing numbers.
```